# Disable GO SMS Pro weekly nag messages

Tags: notifications, go-sms

About once a week, GO SMS Pro "receives" (I don't know if it comes from somewhere or if it's written into the application) a nag message from "c10000@go.chat" along the lines of:

> Most of users loves GO SMS Pro because of themes. Thinking of cool & stylish messaging experience? Try out another bestseller: [ColorGlass Theme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms.theme.getjar.colorglass)  (Apply it through menu->theme)

It's extremely annoying. I believe I've logged out of GO Chat (though it tends to log itself back in without asking and won't stay disconnected), and have tried going through the app's settings multiple times without finding any way to kill these notifications. They're driving me batty.

Comment: My guess is the only way to disable it is to pay for the Premium version.

Comment: Premium… version? I can't find such a thing, unless you mean the themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to blacklist the messages by pressing and holding over the "conversation" in the list and selecting "add to blacklist."  This removed the messages and I haven't gotten any new nag messages from them since.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this will work but I can't test it fully because I never updated Go SMS to the "nagging" new version after reading all the complaints in the reviews...

You have to be rooted.  If you are, install [Root Firewall Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.firewall) and block internet traffic for Go SMS.  I don't get those nagging reminders but I tried it and I was still able to send and receive SMS messages but I could not use features that use the internet like the Go Chat. If you want to download a new theme or use one of the data dependent service periodically you can just toggle the block off from the firewall app and put it back on when you are done. Obviously this won't help you if you use those data dependent extra services regularly.

**Alternatively, if you are not rooted you can revert back to version 4.56 of Go SMS.  You can [download this version directly on the Go SMS website](http://gosms.goforandroid.com/?p=292).**  This is the version I have and I don't get any of those annoying nags.  When I started typing this answer I didn't think they'd post past version but now that I see that they do I'd say this is probably the better option.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I already have [DroidWall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) so it should be simple to give the firewall trick a try. Sounds like you've already gotten the result I want, so I'll try it for a while and come back in a week or so to accept your answer once I confirm that it works. :)

Comment: Good luck.  It's really a shame they mucked the whole app up with those annoying nags but I guess you get what you pay for.

Comment: Additional apps to block: [AdAway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adaway) (with custom lists and a 'track web activity' beforehand) and [Droidwall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free).

Comment: @ce4 Do you think using a hostfile fix in AdAway would work? Go SMS doesn't use popups or banners, they send you fake text messages nagging you to buy their premiums service.  I don't believe they are real text messages going over the SMS service but I do think they are a sort of push notification of some kind.

Comment: You already said, blocking internet for Go SMS completly fixes it. If you know what hostnames Go SMS wants to contact: Block them. It's just a more specific way to block internet access.

Comment: AdAway isn't a bad idea; goodness knows I already use it to block tons of other things. Matt's suggestion of simply blocking GO SMS Pro from accessing the Internet at all seems to be working, though. In either case, the "cure" would most likely wind up blocking all use of the GO Chat function (not that I ever wanted it, but it should be noted for others who may read this question).

Answer (score 2):

I just texted "stop" to the message and got a reply back stating "Got it, thanks".

All done.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to click on that message and then go to the top right corner and then click disable and confirm